# python struct, Byte order and Alignment for Network application and difference between unsigned int and unsigned long

Tags: python, struct, endianness

I have 2 questions about `struct` in the python documentation:

[Byte Order, Size, and Alignment](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) : For Network communication should i use `!` instead of `=` ?
eg: `struct.pack("!BBH", 1, 12, 512)` or `struct.pack("=BBH", 1, 12, 512)` ?

[Format characters](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/struct.html#format-characters) : What is the difference between unsigned int (I) and unsigned long (L), since both are 4 bytes?

Thank you for your time, and forgive me if its a silly question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your code to produce the same output wherever it is run, why would you **ever** use `=`? So of course, yes, you should use a code that means the same thing to everyone. The standard is `!` so use `!`.

Read the header above the format code table:

> The ‘Standard size’ column refers to the size of the packed value in bytes when using standard size; that is, when the format string starts with one of '<', '>', '!' or '='. When using native size, the size of the packed value is platform-dependent.

So, if you use the `@` format code or omit the format code, the size of `I` and the size of `L` could theoretically be different, depending on your platform.