# Unsigned int VS Unsigned long in python struct module

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, sockets, decode

I was reading python struct module's [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) and found interesting thing.

[image]

Unsigned int and unsigned long both equals 4 bytes there.

But, as i know, **unsigned int** can be 2 or 4 bytes, depended on CPU.

So, here is the question. I have PC with little-endian system. This PC share some data via local net. I want to receive this data in another PC (with some endian system, which i don't know) via socket.
I know, that host PC will send 4 variables which are **uint32_t**.

How should i unpack these values in python and why? Should i use **unsigned long** or **unsigned int**? In docs they have the same size. So, the format string will look like **4L** or **4I**?

And additional question - how should i avoid endianness conflicts? Host PC is 100% little endian and it won't change in the future. Client PC can be different, so, should i write a struct string like that: **<4L** (or <4I, depended on the previous question)? Or i should use **!4** bc i receive data from local net (via socket)?

Research in some [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823134/python-struct-byte-order-and-alignment-for-network-application-and-difference-b) [questions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=msvc-170) didn't help a lot, so, here i am.

Pls, shed light on this issue, as long as i messed with this topic a bit.

Comment: If you have a binary communication protocol (one that doesn't use plain text formats) then you need to have it well-defined before implementing it. Including defining the sizes of all data, and their byte order. Then the applications using the protocol will have to adapt to the protocol and its definition, including byte-swapping words and using appropriate local types. Though these days there's seldom any need to not use UTF-8 encoded text-based protocols.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yeah, i would be happy to use UTF:) But i have a deal with robot controller, which is written on C and it just send all data around the local net. So, the controller has been written by other group of programmers, so, they don't want to change anything. In fact i have a deal with a C structure, which has some **double** values, some **uint8_t** and **uin32_int**. How should i transcode this integers on python side?

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add all requested information or clarification to the question. If the robot controller just sends binary structures, then you have to analyze the size and endianness of the data and possible padding in the binary structure representation and take this as the protocol specification. This might be specific to the platform (CPU, OS, compiler, maybe compiler version and/or options) and might change in future if they change anything related to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with the "C type" column? As far as you and I are concerned, this is just 'some' library in Python. You want to read these next 4 bytes as a unsigned integer? Just use `struct.unpack('I', buffer)` or `struct.unpack('L', buffer)`, it clearly does not matter.

Also, I'm not sure what you mean by the character "4" in `4L` or `4I`, unless you're trying to parse exactly 4 unsigned 4-byte integer numbers from the buffer (16 bytes in total).

Comment: Yeah, i want to read 4 integers. In fact, i have a deal with kinda bigger C structure, so i need to write quite a long structure string to unpack this structure.